# how to remove everything but letters, numbers and ! ? . ; , @ ' using regex in python pandas df?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, text-mining

I am trying to remove everythin but letters, numbers and ! ? . ; , @ ' from my python pandas column text.
I have already read some other questions on the topic, but still can not make mine work.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                  'text':['hey+ guys! wuzup',
                              'hello p3ople!What\'s up?',
                              'hey, how-  thing == do##n',
                              'my name is bond, james b0nd']}
                )
```

Then we have the following table:

```
id                         text
1              hey+ guys! wuzup
2      hello p3ople!What\'s up?
3     hey, how-  thing == do##n
4   my name is bond, james b0nd
```

Now, tryng to remove everything but letters, numbers and ! ? . ; , @ '

First try:

```
df.loc[:,'text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r"^(?!(([a-zA-z]|[\!\?\.\;\,\@\'\"]|\d))+)$",' ',regex=True)
```

output

```
id                         text
1              hey+ guys! wuzup
2       hello p3ople!What's up?
3      hey, how- thing == do##n
4   my name is bond, james b0nd
```

Second try

```
df.loc[:,'text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r"(?i)\b(?:(([a-zA-Z\!\?\.\;\,\@\'\"\:\d])))",' ',regex=True)
```

output

```
id                         text
1                  ey+ uys uzup
2              ello 3ople hat p
3            ey ow- hing == o##
4          y ame s ond ames 0nd
```

Third try

```
df.loc[:,'text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'(?i)(?<!\w)(?:[a-zA-Z\!\?\.\;\,\@\'\"\:\d])',' ',regex=True)
```

output

```
id                         text
1                 ey+ uys! uzup
2           ello 3ople! hat' p?
3           ey, ow- hing == o##
4         y ame s ond, ames 0nd
```

Afterwars, I also tried using re.sub() function using the same regex patterns, but still did not manage to have the expected the result. Being this expected result as follows:

```
id                         text
1               hey guys! wuzup
2       hello p3ople!What's up?
3          hey, how-  thing don
4   my name is bond, james b0nd
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Links that I have seen over the topic:

[Is there a way to remove everything except characters, numbers and '-' from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364852/is-there-a-way-to-remove-everything-except-characters-numbers-and-from-a-st)

[How do check if a text column in my dataframe, contains a list of possible patterns, allowing mistyping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570950/how-do-check-if-a-text-column-in-my-dataframe-contains-a-list-of-possible-patte)

[removing newlines from messy strings in pandas dataframe cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells)

https://stackabuse.com/using-regex-for-text-manipulation-in-python/

Comment: A bread and butter example of "how to ask a question". Example dataframe, your attempts, expected output and links to answers which are close. +1

Comment: This is still an unclear question. If by letters and numbers you mean `[A-Za-z0-9]`, how do you define *ponctuations and some other characters*?

Comment: I edited it to specify what I meant by some other characters! And thanks @Erfan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df.text.str.replace("(?i)[^0-9a-z!?.;,@' -]",'')
Out: 
0                hey guys! wuzup
1        hello p3ople!What's up?
2          hey, how-  thing  don
3    my name is bond, james b0nd
Name: text, dtype: object
```